# How to remove black space when deleting widgets in PyQt5

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, qt5, qpushbutton

I have a code to generate a GUI with PyQt5 that enables a user to create multiple buttons (QPushButton) based on an entry (QLineEdit), and to delete these buttons when pressing an "X" button (deleteLater()).

My problem is that when deleting some of these buttons by pressing the associated X-button, this leaves a small empty space where the buttons were initially, and I therefore wonder how to remove these spaces?

Image of the empty spaces

[image]

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QScrollArea, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My Program")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1500, 1500)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        widgets = MainWidgets()
        self.setCentralWidget(widgets)


class MainWidgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(4, 1)

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("Labels")
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet('''
            QGroupBox::title {
                subcontrol-position: top center;
            }
        ''')

        right_column_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        right_column_layout.addWidget(scrollArea)
        scrollArea.setWidget(RightColWidgets())

        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 5, 1, 5)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)


class RightColWidgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.labelEntry = QLineEdit(self)

        self.addLabelButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.addLabelButton.setText("Add Label")
        self.addLabelButton.clicked.connect(self.addNewLabel)

        self.emptyspace = QLabel(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelEntry, stretch=0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.addLabelButton, stretch=0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.emptyspace, stretch=1)

    def addNewLabel(self):
        labelname = self.labelEntry.text()
        newLabelItems = Labels(self, labelname)

        self.layout.insertWidget(2, newLabelItems)


class Labels(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, labelname, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.mylabelname = labelname
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.labelButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.labelButton.setText(str(self.mylabelname))
        self.labelButton.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {border: 1px solid back; background: rgba(103, 186, 181, 0.5); padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px}
        """)
        self.labelButton.clicked.connect(self.printbutton)
        self.buttonErase = QPushButton(self)
        self.buttonErase.setText("X")
        self.buttonErase.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {border: 1px solid back; padding-right: 5 px; padding-left: 5 px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px}
        """)
        self.buttonErase.clicked.connect(self.erasebutton)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelButton, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonErase, stretch=0)

    def printbutton(self):
        print('clicked:', self.labelButton.text())

    def erasebutton(self):
        self.labelButton.deleteLater()
        self.buttonErase.deleteLater()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # app.setStyle('Fusion')
    window = MyWindow()
    window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the children does not delete the container, so what you see is the empty `Labels` widget with the spacing of its layout `contentsMargins()`.

A simple solution could be to directly connect the button with its own `deleteLeter()`, which automatically deletes its children:

```
        self.buttonErase.clicked.connect(self.deleteLater)
```

A *better* solution would be to connect the signal to the *parent* and let it do everything necessary in a *cleaner* way, as you might need to keep track of the existing widgets (for instance, to remove them from the list of currently existing labels):

```
class RightColWidgets(QWidget):
    # ...

    def addNewLabel(self):
        labelname = self.labelEntry.text()
        newLabelItems = Labels(self, labelname)

        self.layout.insertWidget(2, newLabelItems)
        newLabelItems.buttonErase.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.deleteLabel(newLabelItems))

    def deleteLabel(self, widget):
        self.layout.removeWidget(widget)
        widget.deleteLater()
```

Obviously, in this case you don't need to connect the `clicked` signal in the `initUi` of the `Label` class anymore.

Note that [`layout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout) is an existing (and *dynamic*) property of any QWidget, so you should not overwrite it.